# Collision resolution: Displaying sharp and natural note at same time

Tags: lilypond

How do I display equally valued notes, one with an accidental and one natural, at the same time in different voices without them being merged? I tried using \mergeDifferentlyHeadedOff and \shiftOff but it doesn't work.

I want the first note (d natural) to be written after the d flat octave so that it is not merged into one.

```
<<
{d!='8 }
\\
{<des, des'>8 }
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do the trick:

```
\version "2.19.82"

<<
  {
    d'!8 
  } \\
  {
    \once \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = #1.1
    <des, des'>8 
  }
>>
```

Producing:

[image]